# BG and loop space. Which spaces occur as BG?

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $\Omega X$ be the loop space of a connected pointed space $X$, which has an $\infty$-groupoid structure. Then is $B \Omega X$ weak equivalent to $X$? (note that we used the $\infty$-groupoid structure of $\Omega X$ to construct the $B$).

If not, what is a counterexample?

Now, $\Omega B G$ is known to be $X$.

Comment: Every space has an $\infty$-groupoid structure; you mean an $\infty$-group structure. And yes; $B$ and $\Omega$ are part of an equivalence between connected pointed spaces and $\infty$-groups, or if you prefer grouplike $E_1$ spaces.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks so much Qiaochu!!! Can you help me find a place where this is shown?

Comment: Try the references here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/May+recognition+theorem#statement